# WCF required parameters in wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf

Assume i have a method in my WCF Service:

```
[OperationContract]
ResponseObj Test(string testString);
```

When i add this WSDL to soapUI the testString will be marked as optinal

```
<tem:Test>
<!--Optional:-->
<tem:testString>?</tem:testString>
</tem:Test>
```

How do i make the testString parameter required? 
Do i need to add something in the OperationContract method? Or are all parameters Optional in the request in soapUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use data contract with `IsRequired` attribute for the properties

```
[OperationContract]
ResponseObj Test(RequestMessage request);


[DataContract]
public class RequestMessage
{
   [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
   public string TestString{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still omit the "request" parameter in the call and get a null object at the server side.